# Not enough arguments for constructor although I use the Option[] Type

Tags: scala, optional-parameters

I'm  new to scala and I have a very simple problem :

I defined a class like this :

```
case class Image (imageId: Long, userId: Option[Long])
```

But if I want to create an instance of this class with only an `imageId` like this :

```
var newImage = new Image(1)
```

I get this error although I'm using an `Option[Long]` :

```
not enough arguments for constructor 
Unspecified value parameter userId.
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reiterate the error message you're not giving it enough arguments. `Option` is not optional in that you have to provide a value for it namely `Some` or `None`. If you don't want to provide a value and want to use a default value you can give one in the constructor like so:

```
case class Image(imageId, Long, userId: Option[Long] = None)
```

Then you can do this and the default value `None` is used.

```
scala> var newImage = new Image(1)
newImage: Image = Image(1,None)
```

Of course, you can still provide a value when you have one.

```
scala> var newImage = new Image(1, Some(42))
newImage: Image = Image(1,Some(42))
```